# Is it possible to create a non-full screen UITableView using Storyboards?

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I'd like to create a view controller with a UITableView in the top of the screen and a fixed view (which would contain various button, etc.) at the bottom. (i.e.: Below of the UITableView's surrounding scroll view.)

Whilst this is pretty trivial using the traditional NIB file approach, there doesn't *currently* (as of Xcode 4.3.1) appear to be a way of doing this using Storyboards that I can find.

As such, I'm just wondering whether this is currently possible and if so what the best approach is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty much the same process as with XIBs:

1. Drag/drop a "plain" UIViewController onto the Storyboard
2. Change the class from UIViewController to your own, custom class that implements UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource
3. Drop/drop a UITableView onto the view controller
4. Connect the delegates to your custom class

Comment: Damn. Think this is one of those "can't see the wood for the trees" moments.

Comment: Pretty much the same, except you can't use refreshControl and other stuff that's all about the uitableviewcontroller, not uitableview

Answer (score 1):

I want to explain how to do this more thoroughly

**first start with the View Controller**

[image: none]

**next drag in the UITableView object** it will fill the entire screen I have no idea why but it does. Just accept it. The good news is you can programmatically move it around (which is good)

[image: none]

**then double check the view controller outlets look like this** (remember you are ctrl-clicking the `VIEW CONTROLLER` not the TableView!!!)

[image: none]

**Then select the TableView in the left hand pane then chose the `=V=` Icon in the left nav**

[image: none]

**for a last step add the code below in viewDidLoad()** and it will make the TableView have a border

```
 //do both of these to ensure ALL The screen goes black (if you want it black)
 self.view.backgroundColor = .black
 tableView.backgroundColor = .black

 tableView?.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: (self.tableView?.frame.origin.y)!, width: (self.tableView?.frame.size.width)!-20, height: (self.tableView?.frame.size.height)!)
```

[image: none]